# mysql driver for qt database fedora

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, fedora

I understand it's the 100s time someone ask this but I'm still unable to have QMYSQL working.
So I installed qt-mysql but I'm still having the

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
```

I copied `/usr/lib64/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so` into `/usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so` but no changes ...

I've also added `QT += sql` into the .pro file.

So what do I have to do ?

P.S. : I'm on Fedora 21 and I'm using QtCreator 3.3.2 based on Qt 5.4.1.

P.P.S : I also checked if the .so had dependencies problem but there's none :

```
$ ldd libqsqlmysql.so 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff665d1000)
libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0x00007fcb07294000)
libQtSql.so.4 => /lib64/libQtSql.so.4 (0x00007fcb07052000)
libQtCore.so.4 => /lib64/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007fcb06b63000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcb06947000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fcb06638000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcb0632f000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fcb06118000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcb05d5b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcb05b56000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fcb05940000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcb0573e000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcb05404000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fcb051fc000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcb07aa6000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just copy the Qt4 MYSQL driver into Qt5. Install it from the same place you installed the rest of Qt5. (Package qt5-qtbase-mysql perhaps: https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/qt5-qtbase-mysql ).

Comment: Oh my god, thanks. I'm so stupid not to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should build mysql driver manually. The only driver that comes with the default installation of Qt is Sqlite driver.

Follow the instructions in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/sql-driver.html#qmysql

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [mySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/).
2. Follow instructions [here](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_load_a_sql_driver_correctly)

> libmysql.dll needs to be located somewhere where it can be found by the application. To make this happen, you can list it in your global PATH in Control Panel/System/Advanced System Settings/Environment variables or put libmysql.dll in the same folder as the Qt dlls in yourQtDirectory/bin.